# retrofit:2.0.2 getting StackOverflowError

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
```

but i am getting

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:141)
```

my json request is like below

```
{
    "Key": "KEY",
    "Token": "TOKEN_",
    "Data": [
        {
            "UserContactID": "",
            "ContactUniqueID": "1",
            "UserID": "7",
"UserContactDetail": [
                {
                    "ContactUniqueID": "1",
                    "KeyName": "Mobile",
                    "KeyType": "Home",
                    "Value": "+91123456789",
                    "IsActive": 1
                },
                {
                    "ContactUniqueID": "1",
                    "KeyName": "Mobile",
}]}
```

Comment: Please post the code for RefelectiveTypeAdapterFactory class @Android.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your gson library to the latest and try again, check this link for latest releases.
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.6.2%7C

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: May be these will resolve your issue

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

Check: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/

https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/retrofit-android/